# changing inheritance to composition

Tags: c++, design-patterns

```
class MyTransport : public ITransport
{

void setSource(ITransport* src) { m_source = src; }

/* implement ITransport using m_source */

private:
  ITransport* m_source;
};
```

I need to load (in runtime) some `ITransport` and customize its output. At the same time I need to provide `ITransport` to my clients. (It was previously achieved by simply inheriting from some `SourceTransport` but now moving to a plugin)

Is this correct way to do so?

Comment: I consider the question a bit unclear... If it suits your need then yes (you are after all the one that decides if the solution is correct). If your question is if what you did is composition from oop point of view : yes, if you are the memory owner of the given ITransport, no if you are not the memory owner (if you are not the memory owner it will be an aggregation).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually my question was about is there a better design pattern to implement "parent" substitution at run time. However this one looks ok..

Answer (score 1):

This approach to interpose your behavior seems fine, but I would get rid of `setSource` and pass the target source in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the Decorator pattern, which seems to express this situation exactly.